# Compare lists and create new one according to content of both

Tags: python, list

I have the following list of lists:

```
a = [[1,0],[1],[0]]
b = [[A,B],[C],[D]]
```

I want to create a new list of list, with the elements of "b" according to the content of "a": In this case, if in the same position there is a "1", we print the letter. If it´s 0, the Position would be empty.

The result that I want with respect to the previous example would be:

```
c = [[A,_],[C],[_]]
```

Edit: What I tried:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if b[i][j] == 1:
              c.append(a[i][j])
```

This obviously create a list with the elements that I want, but it does not differentiate the internal lists. I really tried other things for a time, I didn´t want to give the feeling I didn´t try.

Comment: `c = [[letter if value != 0 else None for value, letter in zip(a_sub, b_sub)] for a_sub, b_sub in zip(a, b)]` but yeah do show what you have tried in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested `for` loop with `zip` + `enumerate`. Note we first create a `deepcopy` of `b`, so that the original list is unchanged.

```
from copy import deepcopy

a = [[1,0],[1],[0]]
b = [['A','B'],['C'],['D']]

c = deepcopy(b)

for idx1, (i1, j1) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    for idx2, (i2, j2) in enumerate(zip(i1, j1)):
        c[idx1][idx2] = j2 if i2 else ''

print(c)
[['A', ''], ['C'], ['']]
```

You can also, if you wish, wrap this in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach using `enumerate`.

```
a = [[1,0],[1],[0]]
b = [["A","B"],["C"],["D"]]

res = []
for i, v in enumerate(b):
    temp = []
    for n, j in enumerate(v):
        temp.append(j if a[i][n] else "_")
    res.append(temp)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
[['A', '_'], ['C'], ['_']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [[1,0],[1],[0]]
b = [['A','B'],['C'],['D']]

for i in range(len(b)):
    temp=[]
    for j in range(len(b[i])):
        if a[i][j]==1: #check value of a
            temp.append(b[i][j]) 
        else:
            temp.append('_')
    b[i]=temp
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
a = [[1,0],[1],[0]]
b = [['A','B'],['C'],['D']]
c = []
for i in range(0, len(a)):
  c.append([])
  for j in range(0, len(a[i])):
    if (a[i][j] == 1):
      c[i].append(b[i][j])
    else:
      c[i].append(None)
```

You can substitute `None` with whatever you want to consider an empty value (e.g. character `'_'`)